# Complex Grouping in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a fairly complicated SQL query that I need to build. Forgive me, I'm not a magical wizard with SQL.

Here's my two tables (significantly simplified):

tableA

```
id   request_id   page_views   step
-----------------------------------
 1   1            0            0
 2   1            0            1
 3   1            0            2
 4   1            0            3
 5   2            0            0
 6   2            0            1
 7   2            1            2
 8   3            0            0
 9   3            0            1
10   4            0            0
11   4            0            1
12   4            0            2
```

tableB

```
id   name         phone       
------------------------------
1    John Deere   111-222-3333
2    Sally Sue    333-222-1111
3    Jacob Clark  434-343-4343
4    Alex Smith   222-112-2112
```

First, there needs to be a join on the tables where `tableA.request_id = tableB.id` to result in:

```
id   request_id   page_views   step   name          phone
----------------------------------------------------------------
 1   1            0            0      John Deere   111-222-3333
 2   1            0            1      John Deere   111-222-3333
 3   1            0            2      John Deere   111-222-3333
 4   1            0            3      John Deere   111-222-3333
 5   2            0            0      Sally Sue    333-222-1111
 6   2            0            1      Sally Sue    333-222-1111
 7   2            1            2      Sally Sue    333-222-1111
 8   3            0            0      Jacob Clark  434-343-4343
 9   3            0            1      Jacob Clark  434-343-4343
10   4            0            0      Alex Smith   222-112-2112
11   4            0            1      Alex Smith   222-112-2112
12   4            0            2      Alex Smith   222-112-2112
```

From that table, I want groups to be returned if they match the conditions below. By group, I mean groups of rows that have the same `request_id`. Here's the conditions:

1. Of the rows in a group, none have `page_views` greater than 0.
2. Of the rows in a group, none have `step` greater than 2.

If either of the two above conditions fail, the entire group won't be returned. So here's what should be returned:

```
id   request_id   page_views   step   name          phone
----------------------------------------------------------------
8    3            0            0      Jacob Clark   434-343-434
9    3            0            1      Jacob Clark   434-343-434
10   4            0            0      Alex Smith    222-112-2112
11   4            0            1      Alex Smith    222-112-2112
12   4            0            2      Alex Smith    222-112-2112
```

The "3" group (or Jacob Clark) didn't have any rows where `page_views` is greater than 0, and none of the rows have `step` greater than 2. Same with the "4" group (or Alex Smith).

So that's the problem. I need a single SQL query that will handle all of that. The first join can be a subquery, no problem:

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM (
    SELECT tableA.*, tableB.name, tableB.phone
    FROM `tableA`, `tableB`
    WHERE tableA.`request_id` = tableB.id
) sub
```

After that, I'm not so sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `join` clauses can be as complex/simple as you want. `join 1` is totally valid, and simply joins ALL records. it really boils down to the join clause returning a boolean true (join the records being considered) or false (exclude the records). what the expression is, is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the max views and steps (by request_id) separately in a subquery, and then use the request_id's with small enough max values:

```
SELECT a.*, b.name, b.phone
FROM (
   SELECT request_id
   FROM tableA
   GROUP BY request_id
   HAVING MAX(page_views) <= 0 AND MAX(step) <= 2
) AS sumQ
INNER JOIN tableA AS a ON sumQ.request_id = a.request_id
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.request_id = b.id
;
```

or, alternatively:

```
SELECT a.*, b.name, b.phone
FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.request_id = b.id
WHERE a.request_id IN (
     SELECT request_id
     FROM tableA
     GROUP BY request_id
     HAVING MAX(page_views) <= 0 AND MAX(step) <= 2
  )
;
```

In my experience, the first version is usually faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select  A.id, A.request_id, A.page_views, A.step,
        B.name, B.phone
From    TableA  A
Join    TableB  B   On  A.request_id = B.Id
Where   Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    TableA  A2
    Where   A2.request_Id = A.request_id
    And     (A2.page_views > 0 Or A2.step > 2)
)
```