# Grab top row from GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Going off of my last question: [Complex Grouping in SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514770/complex-grouping-in-sql-query)…

In each grouping, I'd like to grab only the row with the highest 'step' value.

This is the query we came up with in the last question:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM (
    SELECT request_id
    FROM tableA
    GROUP BY request_id
    HAVING MAX(page_views) <= 0 AND MAX(step) <= 2
) AS sumQ
INNER JOIN tableA AS a ON sumQ.request_id = a.request_id
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.request_id = b.id
```

That returns:

```
id   request_id   page_views   step   name          phone
----------------------------------------------------------------
 8   3            0            0      Jacob Clark   434-343-434
 9   3            0            1      Jacob Clark   434-343-434
10   4            0            0      Alex Smith    222-112-2112
11   4            0            1      Alex Smith    222-112-2112
12   4            0            2      Alex Smith    222-112-2112
```

Which is what I wanted, however, I realized that in each group (group by request_id) I only need the row with the highest 'step' value. How can I modify my existing query to return only:

```
id   request_id   page_views   step   name          phone
----------------------------------------------------------------
 9   3            0            1      Jacob Clark   434-343-434
12   4            0            2      Alex Smith    222-112-2112
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then include `step` in the logic:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM (SELECT request_id, MAX(step) as maxstep
      FROM tableA
      GROUP BY request_id
      HAVING MAX(page_views) <= 0 AND MAX(step) <= 2
     ) sumQ INNER JOIN
     tableA a
     ON sumQ.request_id = a.request_id AND
        sumQ.maxstep = a.step INNER JOIN
     tableB b
     ON a.request_id = b.id;
```

Comment: Good answer.  Kyle the one thing to note with this answer though is that if there are ties meaning more than 1 record for a request_id share the same MAX(step) you will get more than 1 record still.  If you want to randomly choose only 1 of those you will need to use a rownumber which I am sure Gordon certainly knows if that's what you desire

Comment: Thanks Matt. It's actually okay if I get multiple rows with the same request_id per group.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting an `ORDER BY` on the `step` field and then take the `TOP` record?

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 request_id
        FROM tableA
        GROUP BY request_id
        HAVING MAX(page_views) <= 0 AND MAX(step) <= 2
        ORDER BY step DESC
) AS sumQ
INNER JOIN tableA AS a ON sumQ.request_id = a.request_id
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.request_id = b.id
```

Comment: this will only give the OP 1 request_id, but he is wanting the top record for each request_id.

Comment: Matt is correct. This would not give me what I wanted.